# Legend Color -Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have implemented the following project: http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/9/

I could not able to come up any solution which allow me to change legend text color. It comes black as a default but I would like to make it red or green.

In the following section, I want the Path1, Path2 legends to be red.

```
series: [{
 name: "Path1",
 data: stats,
 markers: {
  visible: false,
 }
 }, {
  name: "Path2",
  data: stats2,
  markers: {
   visible: false
  }
 }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following lines, it allows to change legend color.

```
legend: {
    labels: {
      font: "20px sans-serif",
      color: "red"
    }
  },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/10/